# Add #primary at the end of navlink permalinks on single posts

Tags: functions, permalinks, filters, url-rewriting, urls

I'm trying to add `#primary` at the end of the permalinks to the previous- and next post on all single post pages, to jump past the header directly to `<div id="primary">` when going to the previous or next post.

Can anyone give me a hint on how to do this?

Sorry if the question is to basic for this forum. From what I can see in my searches, this question has not been posted in the forum before.

Eric

---

Update: I eventually managed to cut, paste and modify some code that seems to work. I've pasted the code below, since this forum should be a database for others looking for answers. If anyone with more experience than me have any suggestions for a better solution, please let us know! /Eric

```
/* Jump past header to div id #primary on single blog posts when clicking previous and next */

add_filter( 'next_post_link', 'add_div_id_to_navlink', 20, 5);
add_filter( 'previous_post_link', 'add_div_id_to_navlink', 20, 5);

function add_div_id_to_navlink( $output, $format, $link, $post, $adjacent )
{
    if ( !$post )
        return $output;

    $title = $post->post_title;
    $title = apply_filters( 'the_title', $title, $post->ID );
    $permalink = get_permalink( $post );

    $inlink = str_replace( '%title', $title, $link );
    $inlink = str_replace( '%date', '', $inlink );

    $inlink = '<a href="' . $permalink . '#primary">' . $inlink . '</a>';
    $output = str_replace( '%link', $inlink, $format );

    return $output;
}
```

Comment: One way would be to get the value of `get_next_post_link` (and the same for previous) and manipulate that string (possibly using `explode`) before outputting it.

Comment: Thanks for your tip @vancoder! I eventually managed to cut and paste some code that seems to work. I'll post the code as an update in the question.